How was the speed of colored light measured in a vacuum?
Light is affected by the change in the speed of the source as the frequency of light changes. This is called the Doppler effect, where the red shift can be observed in galaxies moving away from us.
Was the Doppler effect taken into account when measuring the speed of colored light?
Even with the constant speed of light in a vacuum, the speed of the observer can change the speed of the received light, but what is noticeable is that there is no change in the speed of light regardless of the speed of the observer.
Here this made me wonder if the shift makes us see light differently, doesn't this mean that the Doppler effect on light was neglected when measuring the speed of colored light?
This leads me to a fundamental question: How was the speed of colored light measured in a vacuum?

"the speed of the observer can change the speed of the received light, ". No, it can't, and it doesn't. The Doppler effect does not change  the speed of light.

In vacuo the speed of electromagnetic radiation is independent of frequency. Color does not matter.

What is colored light?

@damian light that is not white: light which has a chromaticity other than white

To add to what @ProfRob said: The Doppler effect results from the speed of light being constant. It's already baked into the formalism.

What do you mean by "colored light"?

The experiment that I am aware of which places the tightest limits is
Schaefer. Severe Limits on Variations of the Speed of Light with Frequency. phys.rev.lett. 82:4964-4966. 1999.
https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/9810479
In this experiment light of 30 keV and 200 keV were found to have the same speed with an experimental uncertainty of $\Delta c/c=6.3 \ 10^{-21}$.

An earlier paper, https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.62.841, while not as precise, utilizes data from a wider range of wavelengths from microwave to UV.
